# What do you call the area you work in? Synonyms for 'work area'

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

This is a two-part question.

What are the different names you use for the AREA OF LAND in which you operate? 'Work area' seems to be an okay description, but I am looking for single-word, more formal synonyms. Neither 'workplace' or 'worksite' are the type of words I am looking for, as workplace would mean a facility like an office and worksite describes where infrastructures are being built.

Part two of my question will also further clarify part one. I wanted to use the synonyms meaning 'work area' in the following fictional situation.

- I am an ice cream truck driver, and I usually work at or around a specific place at a certain time. Then one day, a bunch of kids came and started selling their own ice cream where I sell mine. can I say something like 'Don't invade my [insert synonym] and steal my customers, find your own place to sell ice cream.'

Is the word being used correctly in the above example?

Comment: Territory. Space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the perfect word might be *turf*, but it's informal.

> [turf](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/turf)
>   4. *slang US* the territory or area of activity over which a person or group claims exclusive rights

In an informal context, *invade* might be too formal. I would use *step on*: "Don't step on my turf and steal my customers!" It sounds tough to me.

Formally, you could use *territory*.

> [territory](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/territory)
>   1. a. An area of land; a region.
>   3. An area for which a person is responsible as a representative or agent: *a salesperson's territory.*

Neither word means "work area" by themselves. But in the right context, like the fictional one you have provided, I think the meaning is clear and what you are trying to describe.

Comment: *patch* would also work in a similar informal vein to *turf*. 'Stay off my patch and I'll stay off yours'.